# win-bash cd.. not working?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm absolutely new to bash. I downloaded win-bash (http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/), and I ran the file titled 'start_shell'. Then, I tried some basic commands. 
ls seemed to work perfectly fine, however, I'm confused as to why `cd..` didn't work? It says `C:\Users\USER\shell.w32-ix86/bash.exe: cd..: command not found`. I stuck the zip file in my `C:\users\myname` folder. It seemed to make sense there.

I looked everywhere for an API or documentation of some sorts to get me started, but I couldn't find anything. Suggestions?

Comment: You need to leave a space after `cd` i.e. as `cd ..`

Answer (score 0):

In Unix shells like `bash`, `cd` follows the syntax of other commands and must be separated from its argument by a space: `cd ..`.